# jQuery collection length is 0, although element exists

Tags: javascript, jquery

Surely, I've got to be missing something stupid - for two hours now!

### Given

```
<input style="max-width: 410px;" 
    autofillcontainerid="Requested-For_TopSpan_AutoFillDiv" 
    data-sp-peoplepickereditor="true" 
    class="sp-peoplepicker-editorInput" size="1" autocomplete="off" 
    value="" id="Requested-For_TopSpan_EditorInput" 
    title="Enter names or email addresses..." autocorrect="off" 
    autocapitalize="off" type="text">
```

and

```
console.log( $('input#Requested-For_TopSpan_EditorInput').length );
```

### Result

Console shows 0 (zero). Unless I'm just way off, that means the element isn't being found, despite my having checked the spelling of the input id against the jQuery selector numerous times.

### Questions

Shouldn't length be (at least) 1? If not, why not? More importantly, how can I correctly detect the presence of this input?

Thank you!

Comment: Interesting.. it shows 1 here - http://jsfiddle.net/zpt2x7z6/ .. you could try wrapping your jQuery in a DOM ready handler.. `$(document).ready(function () { ... });`

Comment: Document readiness wasn't exactly the problem but you helped me solve it anyway. Your mention of that made me realize that at the point at which this detection is running the input hasn't been rendered by another script yet. Thank you!!!!!!

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but I don't think there's a length property on jQuery objects... I know `$('').toArray().length` will work because toArray() returns an array of elements.

Comment: @Charly you are wrong